# Testing spring batch job stepScope

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-batch

I'm trying to test a spring batch job that performs a read (get data from another application) process (simple calculation) and write (into the mongodb)

**the reader is @StepScope**

**here is the postConstruct of the read task.**

```
 @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        employees.addAll(getListOfEmployeesBy(affectationMotifService.findAllRegistrationNumbers()));
    }

    public List<EmployeeForSalaryDTO> getListOfEmployeesBy(List<String> registrationNumbers){
        LOG.debug("request to get all the employees by registration numbers {}" , registrationNumbers);
        return coreResourceFeign.getAllEmployeesForSalaryByRegistrationNumbers(registrationNumbers).getBody();
    }
```

When I try to launch the test of the job or what ever test in the application. spring always runs the init() of the read task .. which will fail the test because I need to mock the *coreResourceFeign.getAllEmployeesForSalaryByRegistrationNumbers(registrationNumbers)* .
I can't mock the method because it runs before the test begin.

**here is the test**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SalaryApp.class, SecurityBeanOverrideConfiguration.class})
public class SalaryJobServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    private SalaryJobService salaryJobService;

    @Test
    public void startJob() throws Exception {
        SalaryJobDTO SalaryJobDTO = salaryJobService.start(Collections.emptyList());
        Assert.assertNotNull(salaryJobDTO.getId());
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to deal with spring batch tests. Any recommendation or help will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

@PostConstruct will make sure your method is called immediately after the object is created. Spring application creates all the beans as per the configs while application start. This is expected behavior. If you do not want to call your method during application start up remove @PostConstruct and you can run your test mocking the dependent objects.

Rather you should use readers read method to load your data to the reader.